# NHibernate Linq request .All method not supported

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I would use a .All method in my request, but it seems, it isn't supported.
I have a parameterList, wich contains elements with a value and a name (like a dictionary) and others things.
And Parameters, a list of elements with Value and Name.
All my element in the first list must exist in the second.
The request I would use is :

```
linq.Where(u => (u.ParametersList.All(param =>
     (Parameters.Any(p =>
          p.Value== param.Value && p.Name== param.Name)))));
```

If you have an idea for use something else than the .All, I listen to you :)
I tried

```
!u.ParametersList.Any(param =>
     !(Parameters.Any(p =>
          p.Value== param.Value && p.Name== param.Name)));
```

but I guess Nhibernate don't make differences

I tried also

```
List<System.Tuple<String, String>> ParamTuples = Parameters.Select(p => new System.Tuple<String, String>(p.Value, p.Name)).ToList();
```

So, ParamTuples the elements of my second list

```
linq = linq.Where(url => (url.ParametersList.Any(param =>
     ParamTuples.Any(p => p.Item1 == param.Value && p.Item2 == param.Name))));
```

But it didn't worked neither. Those methods are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

just to give the idea you'll need to count the parameter matches per containing element id and match them with the filterparameter count

```
class Parameter
{
    public virtual Entity Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}

ICriteria filter;
foreach(var param in parameterList)
{
    var crit = Expression.And(Expression.Eq("Name", param.Name), Expression.Eq("Value", param.Value);
    filter = (filter == null) ? crit : Expression.Or(filter, crit);
}
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Parameter>()
    .Where(filter)
    .Select(Projections.Group("Parent.Id"));
    .Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count<Parameter>(p => p.Id), parameterList.Count));

var results = QueryOver.Of<Entity>()
    .WuithSubquery.WhereProperty(e => e.Id).IsIn(subquery)
    .List();
```

Update: as from your answer the above matches all but you want any (off the top of my head)

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Parameter>();
foreach (var param in Parameters)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Name == param.Name && p.Value == param.Value);
}
// building (u => u.ParametersList.Any(predicate))
var u = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "u");
var parametersproperty = Expression.Property(u, "ParametersList");
var anyCall = Expression.Call(parametersproperty, typeof(Queryable).Getmethod("Any"), predicate);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<User, bool>(u, anyCall);

linq = linq.Where(lambda);
```

Comment: unless i'm missing something, the OP requests a Linq equivalent, not a QueryOver

Comment: @Jaguar i don't see the requirement that is must be linq. Nevertheless the idea can be applied to a linq query with subquery